# Selenium element Not selectable

Tags: c#, selenium, kendo-ui

I am having an issue with an element which works with a mouse click and there are some items from which one has to be selected but its unselectable is set to on.

whenever I try to select the elements

*I get back an error
the element is not visible so may not be interacted with*

But the element is visible

we are using a kendo UI multiselect

please help
The Html Code:-

```
<div class="k-multiselect-wrap k-floatwrap" unselectable="on">
<ul id="ProfileEditSharedModel_SelectedIndustrySectorIds_taglist" class="k-reset" unselectable="on" role="listbox">
<li class="k-button" unselectable="on">
<span unselectable="on">Sector 1</span>
<span class="k-icon k-delete" unselectable="on">delete</span>
</li>
</ul>
<input class="k-input" style="width: 25px;" accesskey="" role="listbox" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" aria-owns="ProfileEditSharedModel_SelectedIndustrySectorIds_taglist ProfileEditSharedModel_SelectedIndustrySectorIds_listbox" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false" aria-busy="false">
<span class="k-icon k-loading k-loading-hidden"></span>
</div>
<select id="ProfileEditSharedModel_SelectedIndustrySectorIds" class="bigselect" name="ProfileEditSharedModel.SelectedIndustrySectorIds" multiple="multiple" data-val-required="*" data-val="true" data-placeholder="Select Sectors..." data-role="multiselect" style="display: none;" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false">
<option value="1">Sector 1</option>
<option value="2">Sector 2</option>
<option value="3">Sector 3</option>
</select>
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a soloution using the **JavascriptExecutor**

It worked for me using:

```
((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript(String.Format("$('#{0}').data('kendoMultiSelect').value({1});", "ProfileEditSharedModel_SelectedIndustrySectorIds", 3,));
```

or

```
((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript(String.Format("$('#ProfileEditSharedModel_SelectedIndustrySectorIds').data('kendoMultiSelect').value([values]);", "ProfileEditSharedModel_SelectedIndustrySectorIds", 3,));
```

I was using a kendoMultiSelect there

Comment: If anybody can suggest me another method please help me as I am not able to send multiple values here

Answer (score 0):

Try taking the element in a list first because it may be possible if you are finding element by classname (say), there may be multiple elements with the same classname. Selenium won't search further as it gets the first element by that identifier which may not be visible in your case. So please check that action is performed on the expected element.

Comment: Thanks 
I did try That but i am getting the error element is not visible so may not be interacted with.

Comment: add some wait time before you click.

Comment: then try finding element by some other identifier like XPath or so.
if you could post some HTML of the same i could help better.